# How to dynamically create a class and instantiate it in Java?

Tags: java, class

I'm fairly new to Java and I am coming to it from a C++ background. I am working with a class that has to be extended before it's protected constructor is called. I only need the class in one instance.  Is there a way I can dynamically create the class AND instantiate it at the same time?

I found similar posts but not quite hitting the mark.  I have the following code as an example but of course it's syntactically incorrect.

```
final ffd.tokens.CountryTokens cToken = new class USA extends ffd.tokens.CountryTokens
{
    USA (String value)
    {
        super(value);
    }
} ("USA");
```

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8913406/java-inline-class-definition

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
final ffd.tokens.CountryTokens cToken = new ffd.tokens.CountryTokens("someValue")
{
// override something
};
```

Corrections:

Even with protected methods you can create a Builder that will extend `ffd.tokens.CountryTokens` (pretty crazy huh?)

```
public abstract class CountryBuilder extends ffd.tokens.CountryTokens {
   public CountryBuilder () { super("useless-data"); }    
   public abstract ffd.tokens.CountryTokens build (String val); 
}
```

Using:

```
CountryBuilder builder = new CountryBuilder (){
   @Override
   public ffd.tokens.CountryTokens build(String val) {
      return new ffd.tokens.CountryTokens(val) {};
   }
};

builder.build("USA");
builder.build("Canada");
```

I think you get the idea.

Comment: The problem is the CountryTokens counstructor is protected.

Comment: That's pretty cool and I keep forgetting about that pattern. But I was just hoping there was a one-liner solution.  Thanks for all the great input though.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it. I'm always thinking dynamic allocation with Java but if I simply create a local instance I did it this way.

```
class USA extends ffd.tokens.CountryTokens
{

    public USA() { super("USA"); }

} USA country;
```

Now I have my local variable `country` of type `USA`.