# What does a block of code do after a new operation in Java?

Tags: java, swing

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Example ex = new Example();
        ex.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

Here a block of code follows `new Runnable()`. How do I understand this code? I don't remember we can pass a code block directly to any object in java.

Comment: That is actually creating a "in line" class. See this question --> [java inline class definition][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8913406/java-inline-class-definition

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not a code block. It is an object.

When you say,

```
new Runnable()
```

you are creating an object that implements the Runnable interface, specifically the `run()` method.

As the method name suggests, `invokeLater()` will invoke the `run()` method of your runnable interface implementation object (or Runnable object) at some later point in time.

As another poster mentioned, this is an example of Anonymous Classes. It is really a convenience mechanism to quickly write code in a more concise fashion. If you don't like this, you can do it this way -

Create a new class that implements Runnable -

```
public class RunnableImplementation implements Runnable
 {
   public void run() 
    {
        Example ex = new Example();
        ex.setVisible(true);
    }
 }
```

Then, the code in your example becomes -

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new RunnableImplementation());
```

Comment: Can you give me more explanation? What is an object? Runnable? But it's not defined yet how can we new it? Also, why we can define a function in main?

Comment: @OneZero You can't `new` it outside of that call. It's anonymous.

Answer (score 4):

It's creating an instance of an anonymous inner class.  Rather than deriving a named class from `Runnable` and creating an instance of it, you can do the whole thing inline.

See [Anonymous Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing any code block, you are actually overriding the `run` method of the `Runnable` class

Answer (score 0):

How do understand this code? This is such called `swing event queue` which helps to prevent concurrency problems. It invokes method `run()` on each `Runnable` object in this queue in sequential order.

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    Example ex = new Example();
    ex.setVisible(true);
  }
});
```

is equivalent to

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new MyRunnable() );
```

where `MyRunnable` is a class that implements the `Runnable` interface with the code you have and is created only for this purpose and cannot be used again.

Note `MyRunnable` is not the actual name, just made it up to show the point.